# AAPT2 error: this error happened as soon as I updated my android studio to the latest version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-3.0, aapt2

I tried "**multiDexEnabled true**" as well as "`android.enableAapt2=false`", but the error continues to come. There seems to be some build problem. What is it?

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
> at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
> at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
> at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to execute aapt
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:513)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:248)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
> at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
> at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
> at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
> ... 32 more
> Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file processing failed, see logs for details
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.waitForAll(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:121)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.end(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:141)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.close(QueueableAapt2.java:115)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:293)
> ... 48 more
> Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
> at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:491)
> ... 49 more
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
> at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:792)
> ... 50 more
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:177)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> ... 1 more
> Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
> at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
> at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
> at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
> at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

Comment: There should be errors from AAPT2 above the stacktrace. Can you try to build again and post those errors?

Comment: have you get  any solution

Comment: any solutions to this?

Answer (score 5):

Try to change the `compileSdkVersion` to: `compileSdkVersion 28`
and `targetSdkVersion 26`
This works for me.

Comment: This is so frustrating. This hasn't worked either. ;-\

Answer (score 4):

try to execute :

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assemble
```

if doesn't work try w `Clean` and `Rebuild` the project. Finally, go to

> Files > Invalidate caches

Comment: @ReevanthLama can you post the whole log for the build when you run "./gradlew clean assembleDebug"?

Comment: try to delete `Build` folder and rebuild your project

Comment: Yes it helps to find errors on xml files. In kotlin its very hard to find some errors in xml files. There is no correct error reason given . In terminal after running above commands then I got error log easily

Comment: this is indeed the way to catch those hidden errors like i forget to add '#' in the color code string , instead of the nice error i was getting a star war console error the ship is about to destroy .. why you do this Google

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the PNG files it might be corrupted. Sometimes the images are listed as PNG but are not real PNGs.

You can get the list of such images by typing the following code in android terminal

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" | xargs -L 1 -I{} file  -I {} | grep -v 'image/png; charset=binary$'
```

After that, you can convert those to PNG and try again.

Don't add this `android.enableAapt2=false` as it is deprecated and won't be supported.

Comment: I get this on AS Ver 3.1.1: 'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem when trying to use data bind and declaring the layout tag. What I did to resolve the issue after so many attempts was that on your root layout when you are not using data bind say for example this

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">     </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

remove the

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

and just put it on your layout tag(**that is if you are using data binding**)

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

</layout>
```

and hopefully it will work. the `android.enableAapt2=false` didn't work for me so I have to remove everything and try to figure out why I get the error when I put layout tag and use data binding thus I came up with the solution. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me when I updated Android studio to 3.4.0.
I did  change in Project level **build.gradle** file...

```
dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'    //Previus default set up

       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' // Now working fine

    }
```