# com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed after updating android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating android studio,i am getting this error.how to fix this??

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:358)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:219)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:3:5-50: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:5:5-62: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:4:5-64: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:3:5-50: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:5:5-62: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:4:5-64: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.close(WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.kt:67)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:268)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:3:5-50: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:5:5-62: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:4:5-64: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create(Aapt2Exception.kt:45)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create$default(Aapt2Exception.kt:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:97)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteCompileException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:55)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:28)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:71)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon$default(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.run(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:34)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:434: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:442: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
/home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:461: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create(Aapt2Exception.kt:45)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create$default(Aapt2Exception.kt:39)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doCompile(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:152)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.compile(Aapt2Daemon.kt:81)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:170)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:37)
    ... 10 more
```

I followed this questions and tried to apply the solutions but still couldn't fix this issue.
[Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709023/errorjava-util-concurrent-executionexception-com-android-builder-internal-aapt)

[AAPT2 error: this error happened as soon as i updated my android studio to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399005/aapt2-error-this-error-happened-as-soon-as-i-updated-my-android-studio-to-the-l)

Comment: remove aapt2 enable line from gradle.properties this is no more in latest android studio

Comment: i dont have any properties like that in my gradle properties

Comment: [I had this issue while using androidx libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249713/can-not-build-the-project-after-upgrading-to-android-p) against api 27, upgrading to 28 resolved

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fix this one:

```
Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:3:5-50: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
```

Comment: it is coming from auto generated build intermediates

Comment: i deleted that resource file and the issue got resolved.

Comment: that error didnt pop up until i updated gradle :@ and i am just wondering

Comment: Yes, I had same issues yesterday

Comment: hope everyone is going to enjoy the magic of gradle and studio

Comment: this is because aapt2 got stricter again, to fail early at build time instead of crashing at runtime (IDs can only have no value or refer to other IDs, they cannot have for example string values in them).

Answer (score 30):

The problem got solved when I used:

```
./gradlew app:assembleRelease
```

instead of

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: i had the same problem when compiling the app from command line (from Android studio  everything was ok) and adding the "app:" solved the problem

Comment: I can't believe this actually worked after ages of trying everything else. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have no error in your ids.xml file.

Comment: A little bit more information would be cool. What kind of error to look for, or something related as how that error came to be. Otherwise, this answer would be better fit as a question comment. =)

Comment: Look for unexpected character in your ids.xml, like - or @ or any character that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Much better @poskefi =) Now, people pay more attention to the answer that to the comments. To make your answer more informative/appealing, you should include that information in it. Luckily you can edit your answer to append said information ;)

Comment: What if, there's no such file?

Answer (score 5):

### This is what solved the problem for me:

In my `ids.xml` file I had this code which worked fine before the android studio upgrade:

```
<resources>
    <item name="faqID" type="id">faq</item>
</resources>
```

Changed it to:

```
<resources>
    <item name="faqID" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

And everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

Just need to learn how to read error code.
Please read the error log carefully

in this case

**this is the main issue on your xml**

> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

**Where?**

> /home/protocol/DialerCheckout/WorkProjects/Nexge_Talk_New_UI/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading buildVersionTools to 28.0.3 solved my issue.

Comment: Make sure that the ```compileSdkVersion``` is **28**

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was on color.xml in which invalid color name found and it did produce following error

```
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
```

I checked the logcat error and I found this line of stack trace

```
 C:\\MyProjectPath\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
```

Then I had a look into it and I found my color code was wrong then I fixed it and it compiled well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error the android build output gave me three options i clickced **Run with --stacktrace**  after that it rebuild and showed me the line of the error like this `layout/registeration_user_fragment.xml:86: error: not well-formed (invalid token).`

Answer (score 0):

error in my application;
Compiler SDK for one of the libraries was giving an error because it was Version = 27.

The problem was solved when I edited Compiler SDK Version = 28 for all libraries.

Comment: how did you do that? please help me

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the build.gradle(app):

```
    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
    }
    aaptOptions {
      cruncherEnabled = false
    }
```

That's all.

Answer (score -1):

I migrated to AndroidX by selecting following in Android Studio Menu options

> Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX

Later I faced this AAPT issue, Linker issue etc. I fixed it by the following changes

In **all modules** I have updated  `compileSdkVersion 28`

Still if you are facing issue then clean project and rebuild project. In all modules all classes imports are from the support libraries and used other version libraries excepet AndroidX. Just delete those imports then automatically AndroidX will import those components.

```
Click on File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Compiler
```

In that command line option I mentioned as **--stacktrace** for the details log when you build project.

In details, I came to know that few classes still having old imports which are not androidx migrated, so I checked imports for the all the classes.

--Vinod