# com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

After updating Android studio 3.2.1. i am facing above issue

i had go through [com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed after updating android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512326/com-android-builder-internal-aapt-v2-aapt2exception-android-resource-compilatio]) but no useful.

Previously i have faced [Build errors after Android Studio 3.2.1 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790020/build-errors-after-android-studio-3-2-1-upgrade) issue after adding this lines project level gridle iam getting above issue

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // <--here
    }
 }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // <-- here
    }
}
```

This is the Error log :

```
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
Output:  warn: removing resource com.viotalk:string/account_settings_confirm_password without required default value.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3510: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_text_primary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_text_primary)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3511: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_text_secondary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_text_secondary)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3513: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_background_primary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_background_primary)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3514: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_background_secondary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_background_secondary)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3516: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/infocard_border (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/infocard_border)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3517: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/divider (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/divider)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3519: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_cancel_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_cancel_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3520: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_location_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_location_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3521: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_photo_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_photo_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3522: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_picture_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_picture_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3523: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_text_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_text_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3524: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_voice_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_voice_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3526: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_camera (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_camera)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3527: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_document (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_document)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3528: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_location (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_location)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3529: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_photo (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_photo)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3530: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_record (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_record)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3532: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/icon_add_group (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/icon_add_group)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3533: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/icon_add_person (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/icon_add_person)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3534: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/icon_cancel (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/icon_cancel)' not found.

Command: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/bde3fad980e487b411c5a0ae6f8ff6d1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
        /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar\
        --manifest\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules/debug/processDebugResources/manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.viotalk\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
Output:  warn: removing resource com.viotalk:string/account_settings_confirm_password without required default value.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_text_primary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_text_primary)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_text_secondary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_text_secondary)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_background_primary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_background_primary)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_background_secondary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_background_secondary)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/infocard_border (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/infocard_border)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/divider (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/divider)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_cancel_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_cancel_offline)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_location_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_location_offline)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_photo_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_photo_offline)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_picture_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_picture_offline)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_text_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_text_offline)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_voice_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_voice_offline)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_camera (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_camera)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_document (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_document)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_location (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_location)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_photo (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_photo)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_record (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_record)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/icon_add_group (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/icon_add_group)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/icon_add_person (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/icon_add_person)' not found.

/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml:79:5-152:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/icon_cancel (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/icon_cancel)' not found.

Command: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/bde3fad980e487b411c5a0ae6f8ff6d1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
        /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar\
        --manifest\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules/debug/processDebugResources/manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.viotalk\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:97)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteLinkException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:527)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:275)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor616.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
Output:  warn: removing resource com.viotalk:string/account_settings_confirm_password without required default value.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3510: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_text_primary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_text_primary)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3511: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_text_secondary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_text_secondary)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3513: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_background_primary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_background_primary)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3514: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/color_background_secondary (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/color_background_secondary)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3516: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/infocard_border (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/infocard_border)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3517: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/divider (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/divider)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3519: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_cancel_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_cancel_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3520: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_location_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_location_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3521: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_photo_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_photo_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3522: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_picture_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_picture_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3523: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_text_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_text_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3524: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_send_voice_offline (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_send_voice_offline)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3526: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_camera (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_camera)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3527: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_document (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_document)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3528: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_location (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_location)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3529: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_photo (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_photo)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3530: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/ic_attach_record (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/ic_attach_record)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3532: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/icon_add_group (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/icon_add_group)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3533: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/icon_add_person (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/icon_add_person)' not found.
/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3534: error: style attribute 'attr/attr/icon_cancel (aka com.viotalk:attr/attr/icon_cancel)' not found.

Command: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/bde3fad980e487b411c5a0ae6f8ff6d1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
        /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar\
        --manifest\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @/Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules/debug/processDebugResources/manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.viotalk\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doLink(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:177)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:103)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:823)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:525)
    ... 49 more
```

Please help me ?

Comment: Can you post the contents of /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml or at least line 3510 of it?

Comment: Can you post the contents of /Users/user/Desktop/VioTalk_Android_16Nov 2/src/main/res/values/themes.xml?